# How to request data with Angular RXJS Websockets from Bitvavo

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I'm learning about angular and can't figure out how to use RXJS websockets to send messages for data requests with the Bitvavo servers. https://docs.bitvavo.com/#tag/Websocket

The connection is established (see last picture), but I don't know how to request data with this message:

```
{"action":"subscribe","channels":[{"name":"candles","interval":["1h"],"markets":["BTC-EUR"]},{"name":"book","markets":["BTC-EUR","XRP-EUR"]}]}
```

If anyone could provide an example of how to get the data from bitVavo/ or any other server, and how to use this data in HTML, that would be much appreciated.

api url: `wss://ws.bitvavo.com/v2`

Service:

```
  public subject  = webSocket(Variables.BitvavoWssApiUrl);
  public messages$ = this.subject.asObservable();

  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.subject.next(msg);
  }
```

Component:

```
this.BitVavoService.subject.subscribe(
  msg => console.log(msg), // Called whenever there is a message from the server.
  err => console.log(err), // Called if at any point WebSocket API signals some kind of error.
  () => console.log('complete') // Called when connection is closed (for whatever reason).
);

this.BitVavoService.sendMessage('{"action":"subscribe","channels":[{"name":"candles","interval":["1h"],"markets":["BTC-EUR"]},{"name":"book","markets":["BTC-EUR","XRP-EUR"]}]}');


this.BitVavoService.sendMessage({"action":"subscribe","channels":[{"name":"candles","interval":["1h"],"markets":["BTC-EUR"]},{"name":"book","markets":["BTC-EUR","XRP-EUR"]}]});
console.log(liveData$);
```

My firefox browser:
[image]

Postman:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do the component:

```
this.BitVavoService.sendMessage({ "action": "subscribe", "channels": [{ "name": "candles", "interval": ["1h"], "markets": ["BTC-EUR"] }, { "name": "book", "markets": ["BTC-EUR", "XRP-EUR"] }] });



this.BitVavoService.subject.subscribe(
      msg => {
        console.log(msg)
        this.bitVavoWssData = msg;
      }
      , // Called whenever there is a message from the server.
      err => console.log(err), // Called if at any point WebSocket API signals some kind of error.
      () => console.log('complete') // Called when connection is closed (for whatever reason).
    );
```

This is working now.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the correct thing to send the message: `socket.next(...)`, however you need to ensure you are subscribing to your socket.  From the [rxjs docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket#:%7E:text=Pushing%20messages%20to%20the%20server):

> Note that at least one consumer has to subscribe to the created subject - otherwise "nexted" values will be just buffered and not sent

It looks like you are re-implementing features already provided by RxJS WebSocket.  You don't need a `connect()` method nor a `close()` method.  This is because the socket connection is automatically made when there is a subscriber, and closed when there are no subscribers.

Also, you don't need to have a separate `MessagesSubject`, just define `messages$` from your `socket$`.

Your service could be simplified to this:

```js
export class BitVavoControllerService {

  private socket$  = new webSocket(Variables.BitvavoWssApiUrl);
  public messages$ = this.socket$.asObservable();

  sendMessage(msg: any) {
    this.socket$.next(msg);
  }
}
```

Now, in your component, subscriptions to `messages$` will automatically create the socket connection and when all subscriptions have unsubscribed, the socket connection will be closed.

Comment: This is much cleaner, thank you. But when I use the specified query from my post, I still don't get any results like in Postman. Do you have an example on how to get the data from bitvavo and use it in the component.ts.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link to the doc. Everything is working now and it is 10 times easier than I thought. It's weird the documentation did not pop up in my google searches. This weirdly took me 2 days to fix with so many different wrong guides/tutorials.